# Boostrap: Move navbar nav into the right hand (top) of my website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, layout, frontend

I am new to this topic.

Following a tutorial on the internet about HTML/CSS/Bootstrap.

I would like to move the *navbar* to the right hand side (top) of the page, see below what I expect is to see *bar* the right side, I wrote it manually on the screenshot...

[image]

but instead appers in the left side, as it is exaclty above...

I did my research by myself and to fix that I need to add to

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
```

Into

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

But it doesn't work, what could be wrong?

**Here is my code:**

```css
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    #nav-bar {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .navbar {
         background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
        padding: 0 !important;
        /* Remove flex-direction: column; */
    }
    
    .navbar-brand img {
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand li {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand li a {
        color: #FFD166 !important;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .fa-bars {
        color: #FFD166;
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggler {
        outline: none !important;
    }
    
    #banner {
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
       color: #fff;
       padding-top: 5%;
    }
    
    .promo-title {
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    .play-btn {
     width: 45px;
     margin: 20px;
    }
    
    #banner a {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <section id="nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">SERVICES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">ABOUT US</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    
                    <p class="promo-title">Esercizio Luglio 2023</p>
                    <p>Check the tutorials</p>
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="play-btn">Watch Tutorials</a>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="image-fluid" style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
        </section>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to fix that I need to add `mr-auto`

Actually, you would want to set the left margin to auto to take up all available space and move the content all the way to the right. However, in [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#rtl), "Horizontal direction specific variables, utilities, and mixins have all been renamed to use logical properties like those found in flexbox layouts—e.g., start and end in lieu of left and right.

Thefore, you should use the class `ms-auto` to set `margin-start: auto`

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    #nav-bar {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .navbar {
         background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
        padding: 0 !important;
        /* Remove flex-direction: column; */
    }
    
    .navbar-brand img {
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand li {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand li a {
        color: #FFD166 !important;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .fa-bars {
        color: #FFD166;
        font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggler {
        outline: none !important;
    }
    
    #banner {
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
       color: #fff;
       padding-top: 5%;
    }
    
    .promo-title {
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    .play-btn {
     width: 45px;
     margin: 20px;
    }
    
    #banner a {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <section id="nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">SERVICES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">ABOUT US</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    
                    <p class="promo-title">Esercizio Luglio 2023</p>
                    <p>Check the tutorials</p>
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="play-btn">Watch Tutorials</a>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="image-fluid" style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
        </section>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <section id="nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">SERVICES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">ABOUT US</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    
                    <p class="promo-title">Esercizio Luglio 2023</p>
                    <p>Check the tutorials</p>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/play.png" class="play-btn">Watch Tutorials</a>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        
                        <img src="images/home2.png" class="image-fluid" style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
        </section>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**Explanation:**

Since your navbar elements were placed in a flexbox I added `justify-content-end` to the flexbox container containing them.

**Reference:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content